# jquery-ui datepicker multiple languages

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create multiple language supported datepicker on a page and I included language files separately but it only shows default language

```
$(".datepicker, .datepicker-ru").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});

$(".datepicker").datepicker($.datepicker.regional['en']);
$(".datepicker-ru").datepicker($.datepicker.regional['ru']);
```

Answer (score 1):

check out this link : http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Localize calendar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="datepicker-ar.js"></script>
  <script src="datepicker-fr.js"></script>
  <script src="datepicker-he.js"></script>
  <script src="datepicker-zh-TW.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
    $( "#locale" ).change(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option",
        $.datepicker.regional[ $( this ).val() ] );
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">&nbsp;
  <select id="locale">
    <option value="ar">Arabic (&#8235;(&#1575;&#1604;&#1593;&#1585;&#1576;&#1610;&#1577;</option>
    <option value="zh-TW">Chinese Traditional (&#32321;&#39636;&#20013;&#25991;)</option>
    <option value="">English</option>
    <option value="fr" selected="selected">French (Fran&ccedil;ais)</option>
    <option value="he">Hebrew (&#8235;(&#1506;&#1489;&#1512;&#1497;&#1514;</option>
  </select></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I actually cheked it out but I don't want to use SelectBox to change the language.